# Concatenating strings from a multidimensional array overwrites the target string in Perl

Tags: perl, multidimensional-array, concatenation, scalar-context

I've built a two dimension array with string values. There are always 12 columns but the number of rows vary. Now I'd like to build a string of each row but when I run the following code:

```
$outstring = "";
for ($i=0; $i < $ctrLASTROW + 1; $i++) {
    for ($k=0; $k < 12; $k++){
       $datastring = $DATATABLE[$i][$k]);
       $outstring .= $datastring;
    }
}
```

`$outstring` takes the first value. Then on the second inner loop and subsequent loops the value in `$outstring` gets overlaid. For example the first value is `"DATE"` then the next time when the value `"ABC"` gets fed to it. Rather than being the hoped for `"DATEABC"` it's `"ABCE"`. The `"E"` is the fourth character of `DATE`. I figure I'm missing the scalar / list issue but I've tried who knows how many variations to no avail. When I first started I tried the concatenation directly from the `@DATATABLE`. Same problem. Only quicker.

Comment: you seem to have a stray close bracket  at the end of `$k]);` and as always, turn on strict and warnings. Do you have any undef values breaking the concatenation?

Comment: It is not possible to reproduce your problem. Provide input data.

Comment: Did you perhaps read the row values from a file, where the last entry on the `$k` element arrays are `chomp`ed? Meaning you have a bad line endings problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a problem such as two strings `DATE` and `ABC` being concatenated, and the end result is `ABCE`, or one of the strings overwriting the other, a likely scenario is that you have a file from another OS, with the line endings `\r\n`, which are `chomp`ed, resulting in the string `DATE\rABC` when concatenated, which then becomes `ABCE` when printed.

In other words:

```
my $foo = "DATE\r\n";
my $bar = "ABC\r\n";   #  \r\n line endings from file
chomp($foo, $bar);     #  removes \n but leaves \r
print $foo . $bar;     #  prints ABCE
```

To confirm, use

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper $DATATABLE[$i][$k];   # prints $VAR1 = "DATE\rABC\r";
```

To resolve, instead of `chomp` use a regex such as:

```
$foo =~ s/[\r\n]+\z//;
```

Comment: … to resolve, set the input record seperator to the actual line endings: `$/ = "\r\n"` **or** preferably, add the `:crlf` PerlIO layer to the input file handle. Then `chomp` will work as expected.

Comment: @amon Will these solutions work even when you do not know the line endings beforehand? My solution works for all files.

Comment: you are right, the substitution works for all common line endings. If, however, the line endings *are* known, then there are other, more elegant (read: maintainable), and arguably more correct solutions. I'm allergic to silver bullets, encoding detection, and line ending guessing.

Comment: @amon Perhaps you should post your own answer then. This problem is common enough that it should be in some FAQ, so that people can find a quick fix.